# 2 following gates, permutation matrix

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-computer

I have a circuit that has 4 wires and 2 following each other [Toffoli gates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toffoli_gate).

I have permutation matrix for each Toffoli gate (A and B).

Do I have to multiply that 2 matrices to get the entire permutation matrix of that 2 Toffoli gates?

And if I do that is $A\times B$ or $B\times A$?

Comment: Don't Toffoli gates have three wires? Do these 2 Toffoli gates act on the same three wires or two different sets of three?

Comment: I have 4 wires. One gate occupies 3 wires from above. The following gate occupies 3 wires from below. I have permutation matrices for both of them. I want to calculate the entire permutation matrix, which results of the work of these 2 toffoli gates. Thanks much in advance!!!

Comment: One way to do it: take the Kronecker product of the permutation matrices for each of the Toffoli gates with the 2 $\times$ 2 identity matrix, to get two 16 $\times$ 16 matrices, and then multiply those.

Comment: Isn't this question more suitable for a computer science forum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course !

This nevertheless suppose that no time is lost between the two gates, but it is a usual assumption in basic lectures. 
If the state vector $\left| \Psi_0 \right>$ enters at the left of the circuit, then reach the gate A, represented by matrix $A$, then the B one represented by matrix $B$, and end up at the right of the logic circuit as $\left| \Psi_1 \right>$, then the final state is $\left| \Psi_1 \right> = \left( B \cdot A \right) \left| \Psi_0 \right>$, since A applies first, then B.

In your case, I suppose $\left| \Psi_0 \right> = \alpha_{0000} \left| 0 0 0 0 \right> + \alpha_{0010} \left| 0 0 1 0 \right> + \alpha_{0100} \left| 0 1 0 0\right> +  ... $ has 16 entries, since you have 4 wires. Each wire usually represents the time evolution of a single q-bit. A Toffoli gate is usually a 3 q-bits gate, so you have to correctly generalise the Toffoli gate given on the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toffoli_gate). Well, it means that you must put extra diagonal 1's in front of the untouched q-bit. You also have to change block-wise for the second gate I presume. (Please tell me if this last point is unclear for you, it is simpler to understand on a black-board than on internet actually :-) !)

Comment: Ok, you answered P.Shor question during my typing, it's what I expected, the only complication in your case is to find the second permutation matrix (supposing you're not afraid of $16 \times 16$ multiplication matrix of course :-). I let you playing with what I said. If you have further difficulties to find the second matrix, please tell us.

Comment: Don't worry about that if you do not really understand. Kronecker product is an other word for tensor product = how to get one $4 \times 4$ matrix from two $2 \times 2$ matrix, say. I think you already did the job without thinking of the mathematical construction behind ;-).