# 2 following gates, inverse circuit

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-computer

I have a circuit that has 4 wires and 2 following each other Toffoli gates.
The first Toffoli gate occupies 3 wires from above, the following Toffoli gate occupies 3 wires from below.
What will look like the inverse circuit of this entire circuit? 

Thanks much!

Comment: Related question from OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/57811/2451

Comment: Yes, they are started similar, but here is quite another question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if inverse means "how to undo", you just need to calculate the inverse matrix of the product of the two matrices discussed there: 
[2 following gates, permutation matrix](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/57811/2-following-gates-permutation-matrix)

Have fun.

Comment: thanks, but I wonder how will the circuit look like

Comment: Well, it seems to me that a Toffoli gate is its own inverse when looking at the permutation table... By the way circuits and logic gates are supposed to be reversibly, isn't it ?

Comment: Thanks. I'm sorry, I don't understand your question. The circuit for an inverse of B*A will look the same as the circuit for B*A?

Comment: Not in general, but $(B.A)^{-1}=A^{-1}.B^{-1}$ and for Toffoli, $A^{-1}.B^{-1}=A.B$, am I right ?